# How to weight a block above a custom form

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I'm creating a page with a form with the hook_menu:

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['rsvp'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Page',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_form_search'),
    'access arguments' => array("access content"),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

I also have created a block that is to display in the content area of the rsvp page. Right now the form shows above the block. How do I reverse that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7 the output from a page callback will be rendered inside the standard 'Main page content' block. As such it is available to be re-ordered like any other block in the system through the admin UI.

All you need to do is visit the administer blocks page ( http://mysite.com/structure/block ) and move your block above the 'Main page content' block.

Comment: Well I feel stupid now. I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you!